# Taylor series problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

I have this equation:

```
960 - 84.60 * ((1-(1+i)^-12)/i) == 0
```

I simplify `( 1+i)^-12` with a Taylor series `( 1 + x)^a`.

but I obtain `i == 0.087201167` but the real result should be `i == 0.00753` (approximately).

P.S.: My solution

```
( 1 + i)^-12 == 1 - 12i + 78i^2 + 364i^3
```

Then:

```
1 -(1+i)^-12 == 12i - 78i^2 + 364i^3
```

Then I collect `i` and I simplify so I obtain:

```
960 - 84.60 * (12 - 78 i + 364 i^2) == 0
```

And I obtain:

```
-55.20 + 6598.80 i - 30794.40i^2 == 0
```

I apply the Quadratic Formula and I obtain:

`i == 0.087201167` and `i = 2.055`

Comment: I don't see an equation. Could you please provide the code you tried?

Comment: Stefano, is this a question about how to use the [Mathematica software](http://wri.com/) or a question about how to deal with the equation (i.e. math)?

Comment: You lost a factor of 'i' in your "collect and simplify" step. [What this has to do with Mathematica is that, had you used it throughout, this would have been an unlikely occurence.]

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You can check these steps are correct until the last line, the result should be `i == 0.00872 || i == 0.205566` it is different by a factor `10`. Nevertheless approximate solution `i == 0.00872` is correct, it just shouldn't be `i == 0.00753`.

Comment: But How you have found i = 0.00872 and i = 0.205566

Comment: @Stefano From this equation: `-55.20 + 6598.80 i - 30794.40i^2 == 0`. Solution `i = 0.205566` is just an artefact of approximation by a Taylor series. For a bit of `Mathematica` code see the answer by `belisarius`.

Comment: A Taylor Series around 0 would work only for small i. Your solution of 2.055 would be incorrect anyway.

Comment: @Artes Ah. I failed to see a quotient by `i` in the original eqn.

Comment: The taylor series has `- 364i^3` and _not_ `+ 364i^3`.

Comment: Maybe math formatting would help because the algorithmic text might be interpreted different ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
Solve[960 - 84.60*((1 - (1 + i)^-12)/i) == 0, i, Reals]
```

> {{i -> -1.77547}, {i -> 0.00870777}}

```
Plot[960 - 84.60*((1 - (1 + i)^-12)/i), {i, -2, .1}, 
     PlotRange -> {-.01, 0.01}, Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I need the Formula in order to add it to Excel. But I don't obtain 0.0087 that is OK!

Answer (score 0):

Equation

$$ 960 - 84.6 \frac{ 1 - (1+i)^{-12}}{i} = 0$$

Taylor expansion

$$ (1+i)^{-12} \approx -364 i^3+78 i^2-12 i+1 $$

Approximate Equation

$$ 960 - 84.6 \frac{ 364 i^3-78 i^2+12 i }{i} = 0$$

With solutions

$$ i = 0.00872 \;,\;\; i = 0.205566 $$

So what is your question here?